# How to create where conditions dynamically in Knex.js?

Tags: node.js, knex.js

I need to create a query with the where clause according to the parameters that are received, but I don't know how to include some parameters in the where clause. In the code below the four first conditions (customerId, companyId, invoiceId and open) are working well, but I don't know how to include the others (closed, openedFrom and openedTo).

```
const getByParams = (req, res) => {

    const conditions = {}
    if (req.query.customerId) conditions['wo.customerId'] = req.query.customerId
    if (req.query.companyId) conditions['wo.companyId'] = req.query.companyId
    if (req.query.invoiceId) conditions['wo.invoiceId'] = req.query.invoiceId
    if (req.query.open) conditions['wo.finishedAt'] = null

    const onlyClosed = req.query.closed ? 'wo.finishedAt != null' : ''
    const openedFrom = req.query.openedFrom ? `wo.openingAt >= ${req.query.openedFrom}` : ''
    const openedTo = req.query.openedTo ? `wo.openingAt <= ${req.query.openedTo}` : ''

    app.db('workOrders as wo')
        .select('wo.*',
            'wos.serviceId',
            'wos.cost',
            'srv.name as serviceName')
        .leftJoin('workOrderServices as wos', 'wo.id', 'wos.workOrderId')
        .leftJoin('services as srv', 'wos.serviceId', 'srv.id')
        .whereNull('wo.canceledAt')
        .where(conditions)
        .then(wo => {
            const json = JSON.stringify(wo)
            const newJson = convertJson(json)
            res.status(200).send(newJson)
        })
        .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err))
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

refer to https://knexjs.org/#Builder-where

try this:

```
.where((builder) => {

    if (req.query.customerId)
        builder.where('wo.customerId', req.query.customerId);

    if (req.query.companyId)
        builder.where('wo.companyId', req.query.companyId);

    if (req.query.invoiceId)
        builder.where('wo.invoiceId', req.query.invoiceId);

    if (req.query.open)
        builder.whereNull('wo.finishedAt');

    // so on..

});
```

instead of

```
.where(conditions)
```

Comment: Thank you @vedsmith92. It was just what I was looking for and it solved my problem. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you do the same thing with orderBy? I can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

if all filters are AND 'equals' statements, another way is

```
.where({
    ...(req.query.customerId && {'wo.customerId': req.query.customerId})
    ...(req.query.companyId && {'wo.companyId': req.query.companyId})
    ...(req.query.invoiceId && {'wo.invoiceId': req.query.invoiceId})
});
```